# How can I create an array of sequential values through the input of the minimum and maximum values?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I want a logical sequence between 0 and 100 that has 1 number between them, so I set 0 in B1, 100 in B3 and add the formula in B2:

[image]

If I want with 9 numbers between them, I just change the cell where the 100 is:

[image]

Now I want to reproduce this using Google Apps Script so I don't have a circular dependency on my spreadsheet.

```
[[0],
[...],
[...],
[...],
[100]]
```

So far, I've tried this:

```javascript
function between() {
  const min = 0;
  const max = 100;
  const total = 11;
  const seq = (min + max) / total;
  const lst = [[min]];
  let i = 1;
  while (i <= total-2) {
    lst.push([(seq*i).toFixed(2)])
    i++
  }
  lst.push([max])
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('data').getRange(1,2,lst.length,1).setValues(lst);
}
```

However, it doesn't generate the expected values. What should I adjust to get the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By formula

```
=arrayformula(sequence(B3+1,1,B1*B3,(B2-B1))/B3)
```

or, according the the precision you need

```
=arrayformula((sequence(B3+1,1,B1*1000*B3,(B2-B1)*1000)/B3)/1000)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I did some tests and I ended up realizing that the minimum value and the maximum value do not keep being the ones we initially chose. For example, if we want 99 numbers between the minimum and maximum, the minimum becomes 0 and the maximum becomes 35.

Comment: to adjust the precision, try `=arrayformula((sequence(B3+1,1,B1*1000*B3,(B2-B1)*1000)/B3)/1000)`

Comment: Ah, I hadn't paid attention to the precision required to work with this function, thank you very much for the teachings, perfect! It is a solution without the need for circular dependency and spending on GAS runtime quota.

Comment: For sure, I was just finishing testing with real examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your calculation is doing in mathematical terms, but I tried to reconstruct your formula and came up with the following for loop (use this instead of your while loop):

```
for(let i = total - 2; i >= 1; i--) {
  let e = max + i * (min - max) / (total - 1);
  lst.push([e.toFixed(2)])
}
```

Comment: Hello @johndee31415 , I've updated the question a bit to improve the visualization of what is expected, sorry for not being clear. But your solution has already done exactly what it takes!